# MongoDB Filtering Inner Array of Documents During Aggregation C#

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'm relatively new to MongoDB and I've been struggling to join and then filter sub-documents during the aggregation stage using the C# driver.

Suppose I have three different collections. Out of these collections, I want a sales representative, the branch they belong to and the most recent sales based on a date filter.

**SalesRepresentatives:**

```
{ 
   _id: ObjectId('1234'), 
   FirstName: 'John', 
   LastName: 'Doe', 
   BranchId: ObjectId('1111')
}
```

**SalesBranches:**

```
{
   _id: ObjectId('1111'), 
   BranchName: 'Branch 1'
}, 
{ 
   _id: ObjectId('1112'), 
   BranchName: 'Branch 2'
}
```

**SalesHistory:**

```
{
   _id: ObjectId('5551'),
   SalesRepresentativeId: ObjectId('1234'),
   SaleDate: '2023-07-26T11:49:46.205+00:00', 
   Amount: 10
},
{
   _id: ObjectId('5552'), 
   SalesRepresentativeId: ObjectId('1234'),
   SaleDate: '2023-07-25T11:49:46.205+00:00', 
   Amount: 11
},
{
   _id: ObjectId('5553'), 
   SalesRepresentativeId: ObjectId('1234'),
   SaleDate: '2023-07-20T11:49:46.205+00:00', 
   Amount: 15
}
```

The desired results I want to have output should look like.

```
{ 
   _id: ObjectId('1234'), 
   FirstName: 'John', 
   LastName: 'Doe', 
   SalesBranch: { 
      _id: ObjectId('1111'), 
      BranchName: 'Branch 1'
   }, 
   Sales: {[
      { _id: ObjectId('5551'), SaleDate: '2023-07-26T11:49:46.205+00:00', Amount: 10 }, 
      { _id: ObjectId('5552'), SaleDate: '2023-07-25T11:49:46.205+00:00', Amount: 11 }
   ]}
}
```

I construct the initial query like so:

```
DateTime startDate = new DateTime(2023, 07, 25, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc).Date;

var matchFilter = Builders<SalesRepresentative>.Filter.Where(f => f.ID == ObjectId('1234'));
var projFilter = Builders<SalesRepresentative>.Projection.Include(p => p.ID).Include(p => p.FirstName).Include(p => p.LastName).Include(p => p.BranchId);

var pResults = await _mongoDb.SalesRepresentatives.Aggregate() 
   .Match(matchFilter) 
   .Project(projFilter) 
   .Lookup("SalesBranches", "_id", "BranchId", "SalesBranch")
   .Lookup("SalesHistory", "_id", "SalesRepresentativeId", "RecentSales") 
   .Project(new BsonDocument {
      { "_id", 1 }, 
      { "FirstName", 1 }, 
      { "LastName", 1 }, 
      { "SalesBranch._id", 1 }, 
      { "SalesBranch.BranchName", 1 }, 
      { "RecentSales._id", 1 }, 
      { "RecentSales.SaleDate", 1 }
   }).ToListAsync();
```

While this works, it outputs ALL the sales for the matching Sales Representative. But I only want sales where the date of the sale >= `startDate`. I then amend the query like so:

```
var pResults = await _mongoDb.SalesRepresentatives.Aggregate() 
   .Match(matchFilter) 
   .Project(projFilter) 
   .Lookup("SalesBranches", "_id", "BranchId", "SalesBranch")
   .Lookup("SalesHistory", "_id", "SalesRepresentativeId", "RecentSales") 
   .Project(new BsonDocument {
      { "_id", 1 }, 
      { "FirstName", 1 }, 
      { "LastName", 1 }, 
      { "SalesBranch._id", 1 }, 
      { "SalesBranch.BranchName", 1 }, 
      { "Sales", new BsonDocument { 
            { "$filter", new BsonDocument { 
                  { "input", "$RecentSales" }, 
                  { "as", "Sales" }, 
                  { "cond", new BsonDocument {
                        { "$gte", new BsonDocument { 
                              { "$$Sales.SaleDate", startDate }
                           } 
                        }
                     }
                  }
               } 
            }
         }
      }
   }).ToListAsync();
```

but then I get an exception: `Command aggregate failed: Invalid $project :: caused by :: 'Sales' starts with an invalid character for a user variable name.`

What am I doing wrong?

### SOLVED

So it turned out that the filter was incorrectly constructed and the `as` parameter does not like values starting with capitals, i.e. `sale` but not `Sale` and it cannot be the same as the upper-level field name `Sales`, hence `sale`. And this is what we need to refer to when examining the fields.

My *working* filter now reads:

```
   .Project(new BsonDocument {
      { "_id", 1 }, 
      { "FirstName", 1 }, 
      { "LastName", 1 }, 
      { "SalesBranch._id", 1 }, 
      { "SalesBranch.BranchName", 1 }, 
      { "Sales", new BsonDocument { 
            { "$filter", new BsonDocument { 
                  { "input", "$RecentSales" }, 
                  { "as", "sale" }, 
                  { "cond", new BsonDocument {
                        { "$gte", new BsonArray {
                           startDate, new BsonDocument("$toDate", "$sale.SaleDate")
                           } 
                        }
                     }
                  }
               } 
            }
         }
      }
   }).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Weird behaviour, suspect that the variable name `Sales` crash with the field name on the top. Have you tried to rename the variable, or you didn't need the `as` part, and change `$$Sales.SaleDate` to `$$this.SaleDate`

Comment: You could use the `pipeline` argument of `$lookup` to do that additional filtering when the `RecentSales` field is being created. The docs for the raw command are [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#correlated-subqueries-using-concise-syntax) (not sure how that looks in C# though)